# testing multiple variables that are object or not

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get if both variables are object return true else return false

```
var sString = "test string";
var oString = new String("test objects");
if( typeof sString == 'object' && typeof oObject == 'object'){
    alert('true');
} else {
    alert('false');
}
```

> It's alerting fasle. And it's okay.

```
var sString = new String("some test");
var oString = new String("test objects");
if( typeof sString == 'object' && typeof oObject == 'object'){
    alert('true');
} else {
    alert('false');
}
```

> It's alerting false. But should return true!

---

I've tried like this too: `typeof sString && oString == 'object'` but not working.

Comment: Did you actually try `typeof sString && oString == 'object'` exactly, or do you mean you tried `typeof sString == 'object' && typeof oString == 'object'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your code:

```
if( typeof sString == 'object' && typeof oObject == 'object')
```

But your variables are called sString and oString. typeof oObject, if oObject is not defined, will return 'undefined', and that's why it alerts 'false'